# Screen rotation causing TextViews to stop updating

Tags: android, textview, orientation

My app is receiving data from a BlueTooth device 4 times a second, parsing it and then displaying it to the screen. Everything works fine, until the screen orientation changes, then  the textViews revert to their default values set in my onCreate and will not change from there.

I am still receiving the data from my message handler from the bluetooth thread, and the parsing is working fine, but my updateUI() method does nothing. All that is in updateUI() is setting the TextView's text to the value, like tv_text.setText(doubleValue);. Again, this works fine before the screen gets rotated or sleeps.

Does the View ID change when the screen is rotated so my TextView is the wrong one? How do I get around this? I have seen others with problems of the TextView loosing it's data, but I'm not sure if that's the same problem because I am not able to set the text again after rotation.

Thanks.

EDIT: I have discovered some odd behavior.

1. If I rotate the screen before connecting to the BT device, it will work when I connect. But then it stops when I rotate again.
2. When I rotate, the text view displays the value that was last assigned to it BEFORE connecting. For example, if do tv.setText("10"), it will display 10. Then I connect, and it updates with the correct values. Then I rotate, and it does back to displaying 10...
3. The only time I set the text values in in my updateUI() code and that is called after the message is received and parsed.

Now I'm really confused...

**EDIT 2**

OK, I did some more testing ans I think I may have located the cause. When I tried to disconnect the bluetooth connection I found out that it wasn't disconnecting. So then i tried disconnecting before rotating, and then connecting again and it worked.

So I believe that when onCreate is run again, it is duplicating my bluetooth comm thread and ignoring the old one. The problem is I don't know how to make initialize the BTComm object in a way that it will still work when the activity is destroyed and re created, it is still working and can communicate with the UI. Here is some code:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        if (btc == null){
            btc = new BTComm(this, messageHandler);
        }

        tv_temp1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_temp1);
        tv_temp2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_temp2);
        tv_temp1Label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_temp1Label);
        tv_temp2Label = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_temp2Label);
        tv_status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_status);
    }
```

and the handler that handles the messages received from the BT comm class (btc)

```
Handler messageHandler = new Handler() {
         public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
                switch(msg.what){
                case BTComm.MESSAGE_CONNECTED:
                    Toast.makeText(LambdaActivity.this, "Connected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    tv_status.setText("Connected.");
                    mode = MODE_CONNECTED;
                    break;
                case BTComm.MESSAGE_READ:
                    parse(msg.getData().getString("results"), msg.getData().getLong("time"));
                    break;
                case BTComm.MESSAGE_DISCONNECTED:
                    Toast.makeText(LambdaActivity.this, "Disconnected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    tv_status.setText("Not connected...");
                    mode = MODE_NOT_CONNECTED;
                    break;
                }
         }

    };
```

It would work if I disconnected and re-connected each time the screen was rotated, but that would interrupt the function of the app's data logging feature so I don't want to do that... If I lock the orientation to landscape, the screen obviously doesn't rotate and cause this problem, but if the phone sleeps, when it wakes up in portrait more, it then rotates to landscape mode and the problem happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case anyone else is having this problem I have found a fix.

I ended up moving my bluetooth listener to a service, and when it receives the data from the BT device, it then broadcasts it and is received by my UI activity.

Some more information can be found in my other question, here: [Android background task and lifecycle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8828898/android-background-task-and-lifecycle)

Comment: To solve the problem of my TextView (in a ScrollView) not updating with fast streaming text, I tried all the other methods discussed elsewhere on SO : (post)invalidate, requestLayout, runoOnGuiThread etc. Only the BroadcastReceiver worked. I didnt need a service either, just a simple intent b'cast from the thread telling the Activity to update the TextView.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how it will affect a Bluetooth communication, but if you put `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` in your AndroidManifest.xml file for the activity in which you want to be notified of changes, you can deal with those config changes in `onRetainNonConfigurationInstance()`.  This method will be called before your activity is destroyed and rebuilt.

It should be noted that this method is deprecated if you are targeting Honeycomb or later and that you should use `Fragment.setRetainInstance(boolean)`.

Comment: Just a note that Google does not officially endorse this method and I think Reto Meier called it "lazy" at Google I/O

Comment: @oneilse14: When I was first learning how to do this, I had basically taken it from the developer docs [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html#RetainingAnObject).  Seems like it is sanctioned enough that they won't be changing it in the future at least.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you set your reference for the textView chances are the reference to your textview has been lost.

you could also try

```
((TextView)findViewById(yourtextviewid)).setText(doubeValue)
```

This way you aren't statically holding the reference.

Without seeing your code; specifically your activity life cycle functions this is a stab in the dark.

EDIT:
You could try making both the handler and your bluetooth object static that way they would be shared across instances of the class... However, I would recommend looking at a service implementation for the bluetooth connectivity.

Comment: I think that may be it. I'm setting the reference in onCreate(). Id there a place where I can re-set them after the screen rotates or turns off? I will try your code and see if that works, too.

Comment: That code does not seem to work, I have updated my original question.

Comment: Are you sure the textview is your issue and not your bluetooth receiver.. Especially with your update to the problem.

Comment: Try setting the reference to the text view in onResume.

Comment: No luck with that either, but I think I may have figured out the problem... I just don't know the best way to fix it... See my updated question.