# Android background task and lifecycle

Tags: android, multithreading, service, background, lifecycle

I'm currently working on an app that connects to a bluetooth device and receives a message every .25 seconds, then displays that data on screen. The user will also be able to arbitrarily start/stop logging this data to a file on the SD card.

I have tried extending a thread class that listens for the messages from the BT device, and then using a handler to send the data back to the UI thread and display it.

This was working fine, but on configuration changes, like screen rotation, when the activity is destroyed and re-created the BT thread is duplicated and I can no longer communicate with it. I have no problems, if I stop the BT thread in onStop() and re-start it in onResume() but then I need to re-connect to the BT device and if the user was logging data, that would be inturrupted.

What is the correct way to accomplish this functionality? Is there a way to setup my thread so it isn't duplicated or so I can re-connect to it after a config change? Should I instead be looking at a service for my BT connection and logging, and then somehow get a feed from the service to display on the UI?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I instead be looking at a service for my BT connection and logging, and then somehow get a feed from the service to display on the UI?

Yes you should. I think this is a good approach. You should run your thread the logs data in a service, and put the data that needs to be passed to the main UI or activity in a sharedpreference which will give ANY activity access to the information.

I think this would be the best way to go about doing this.

OR

You could use the method provided by alex.veprik

Comment: This is probably the best solution since you would also need to prevent the phone from answering phone calls during the operation as well.

Comment: That is a very good point I hadn't considered. I am unfamiliar with services, but from reading the documentation here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html I think I am starting to get a pretty good understanding.

Comment: Wouldn't storing the data to a SQLiteDatabase be a better choice than a SharedPreference? As long as all of the Activities that need the data are in the same app domain, they should be able to open it.

Comment: The data that needs to feed the UI needs to be updated in realtime so I am thinking the best way to do it would be to broadcast the data and then receive it in my UI thread. Would this be good?

Comment: Hmm....Well you could broadcast it, or you could pass it via intent extras, but i think sharedpreference would be EASY to implement, its overritable meaning you can overrite the same values in real time as you need..@Wizetux you could possible use SQL i think it would be a waste for such a simple task as this though. I think shared preference or intent extra is your best bet. SharedPreference is more realiable as it writes to an xml file.

Comment: Sure, Service is the best way to go. I would prefer it over the simple approach I posted earlier. However, you should not forget that the service can be killed by LowMemoryKiller any time if the device will be low on RAM due to many running activities. 
So even the service will not guarantee running without interruptions. If you return START_STICKY from the Service's onStartCommand then the service will be preserved (re-started after being killed) but still there will be interruption of its running cycle.

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent your activity from re-creating upon config changes.
Just modify the manifest file:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
          android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation" />
```

Comment: Thanks, that does work but I was under them impression from reading elsewhere that that is sort of bad practice. I have been looking into Services, and it is starting to look like that may be the way to go, but I need to find out if it is possible to send messages back to the service so I can send data to the BT device.

Comment: You can send messages back to the service through intents. Take a look a the sample code for the Music player that comes with the Android SDK. They do message passing to a service there.

Comment: There are several ways, like already commented here SharedPreferences, or broadcasting an intent, or the one with Messenger, explained here
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/bound-services.html